# How to loop through key : multi values dictionary in Robot framework?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, robotframework

I got a dictionary in a format like

```
myDict = {"keyA" : ["valA_1","valA_2"], "keyB" : ["valB_1","valB_2"]}
```

and i want to use those items in a for loop, to execute a command like :

```
command --arg1 keyA --arg2 valA_1 --arg3 valA_2
command --arg1 keyB --arg2 valB_1 --arg3 valB_2
```

i tried :

```
FOR  ${key}  IN  @{MY_DICT.keys()}
  FOR  ${val1}  IN  @{MY_DICT.values()[0]}
    FOR  ${val2}  IN  @{MY_DICT.values()[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must take care when using list expansion @ indicator, because you were using it in the dictionary.

Here is a complete working example for you question:

loop_variables.py:

```py
myDict = {"keyA" : ["valA_1","valA_2"], "keyB" : ["valB_1","valB_2"]}
```

loop_in_dict.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables         loop_variables.py
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Loop in Dictionary
    Log    MyDict Variable contains: ${myDict}
    @{commands}=    Create List
    @{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${myDict}
    FOR    ${key}    IN    @{keys}
        ${command}=    Set Variable    command
        ${idx}=    Set Variable    ${1}
        ${command}=    Catenate    ${command}    \ --arg${idx} ${key}
        FOR    ${val}    IN    @{myDict["${key}"]}
            ${idx}=    Set Variable    ${idx+1}
            ${command}=    Catenate    ${command}    \ --arg${idx} ${val}
        END
        Append To List    ${commands}    ${command}
    END
    Log Many    ${commands}
```